# Getting error on using debug = True in app.run

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am new to flask
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(**name**)

```
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

@app.route("/Aj")
def helloAj():
    return "Hello AJ!"
if __name__=="__main__":
     app.run(port=5000)
```

This is giving me proper output, but when I write app.run(debug=True)

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

@app.route("/Aj")
def helloAj():
    return "Hello AJ!"
if __name__=="__main__":
     app.run(debug=True)
```

It is giving me error, following output as

```
* Serving Flask app "__main__" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with windowsapi reloader
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 1
```

Below is the output of %tb command

---

> ```
>      10     return "Hello AJ!"
>      11 if __name__=="__main__":
> ---> 12      app.run(debug=True)
>
> F:\Anaconda-Python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py in run(self, host, port, debug, load_dotenv, **options)
>     988 
>     989         try:
> --> 990             run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
>     991         finally:
>     992             # reset the first request information if the development server
>
> F:\Anaconda-Python\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py in run_simple(hostname, port, application, use_reloader, use_debugger,
> ```
>
> use_evalex, extra_files, reloader_interval, reloader_type, threaded,
> processes, request_handler, static_files, passthrough_errors,
> ssl_context)
> 1048         from ._reloader import run_with_reloader
> 1049
> -> 1050         run_with_reloader(inner, extra_files, reloader_interval, reloader_type)
> 1051     else:
> 1052         inner()
>
> ```
> F:\Anaconda-Python\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\_reloader.py in run_with_reloader(main_func, extra_files, interval, reloader_type)
>     337             reloader.run()
>     338         else:
> --> 339             sys.exit(reloader.restart_with_reloader())
>     340     except KeyboardInterrupt:
>     341         pass
>
> SystemExit: 1
> ```

Comment: are you running it in jupyter?

Comment: if yes
> use %tb to see the full traceback.

Comment: Yes using jupyter notebook, because the URL I am getting in Spyder is not working, giving error as 'This site can’t be reached'. Could you please suggest something in this

Comment: I have done %tb, added the output in question